# How do I get notified if SE tweets my question?

Tags: feature-request, notifications, twitter

Sure I can find out if I see revisions (which I don't check if my question is not edited), but is there anyway for me to be notified? Is there a list maybe I can check of questions tweeted for all sites or per site kind of like the [newsletters](https://stackexchange.com/users/4275979/bclc?tab=subscriptions)?

If none, I request there be one or an explanation as to why there is or should be none.

Adding a keyword: twitter (because tag is not enough)

Comment: It's highly probable that you'll get a Famous/Notable/Popular Question badge for that question, if you haven't already. You can _sort of_ use this as a proxy notification.

Comment: @jimsug: Well, that's debatable and probably highly site-dependent; I have a bountied (and therefore tweeted) question that got three answers in bounty ... and has 198 total views.

Comment: @jimsug which question? did you mean this one?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no functionality at the moment that notifies you if a post gets tweeted.

You can however use the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer (SEDE)](https://data.stackexchange.com/) to [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/aviation/query/344507?accountid=4275979) the [`posthistory table`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678/158100) for rows with typeid = 25 (tweeted) at any time you like during the week (but note that SEDE gets only refreshed once a week).

The query I created for you has logic to iterate over all databases to check each site if posts for your account have been tweeted.

The query requires an accountid and that one can be found by visiting your network account on StackExchange.com and then take the id from the url. Yours is [4275979](https://stackexchange.com/users/4275979/bclc), mine is [281857](https://stackexchange.com/users/281857/rene).

```sql
---- accountid: Account on stackexchange.com! "In the url on stackexchange.com"

-- start create url from dbname
IF OBJECT_ID ( '#siteurl', 'P' ) IS NOT NULL 
    DROP PROCEDURE #siteurl;
GO
create procedure #siteurl
   @dbname nvarchar(250),
   @res nvarchar(250) OUT
   as
   begin
      -- we have three sites that have borked DNS entries
      set @dbname = (case @dbname
      when 'StackExchange.Audio' then 'StackExchange.Avp'
      when 'StackExchange.Audio.Meta' then 'StackExchange.Avp.Meta'
      when 'StackExchange.Mathoverflow.Meta' then 'net.Mathoverflow.meta'
      else @dbname
      end)
      -- and one of those doesn't want to end with .com
      if @dbname <> 'net.Mathoverflow.meta' 
         set @dbname = 'com.' + @dbname
      exec #recursesiteurl @dbname,  @res OUTPUT
   end
GO
-- create url from dbname
IF OBJECT_ID ( '#recursesiteurl', 'P' ) IS NOT NULL 
    DROP PROCEDURE #recursesiteurl;
GO
create procedure #recursesiteurl
   @dbname nvarchar(250),
   @res nvarchar(250) OUT
   as
   begin
      declare @pos integer
      declare @rec nvarchar(250)
       
      set @res = @dbname
      set @pos = CHARINDEX('.', @dbname)
      if (@pos > 0 ) 
      begin
         set @rec = substring(@dbname, @pos+1, len(@dbname))
         exec #recursesiteurl @rec,  @rec output
         set @res = @rec 
                  + '.' 
                  + substring(@dbname, 0, @pos) 
      end
   end;
GO

declare @accountid int = ##accountid:int##  -- 93484

-- all databases
declare  db_c cursor for select [name] 
                         from sys.databases 
                         where database_id > 5 -- skip master, temp, model, msdb, Data.SE

declare @db_c_name sysname   -- holds name of db after fetch
declare @sql nvarchar(max) -- holds build up sql string

-- result table
create table #all_posts ( site nvarchar(250)
                            , id int
                            , title nvarchar(200)
                            , owneruserid int
                            , displayname nvarchar(200));
                            
open db_c
fetch next from db_c into @db_c_name
while(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
begin
    set @sql = N'use '+ QUOTENAME(@db_c_name) +';
               declare @url nvarchar(250)
               exec #siteurl ''' + @db_c_name  + ''', @url output
               insert into #all_posts 
               select @url
               , q.id
               , q.title
               , u.id
               , u.displayname
               from posts q 
               inner join posthistory ph on ph.postid = q.id
               inner join users u on u.id = q.owneruserid
               where ph.posthistorytypeid = 25 -- tweeted
               and   u.accountid = '+ cast(@accountid as nvarchar) + ';'
    exec (@sql)
   fetch next from db_c into @db_c_name
end;
close db_c;
deallocate db_c;

select replace(
       replace(
       replace(site,
         '.StackExchange.com',''),
         '.com',''),
         '.net','') as [site]
     , 'http://' 
     + site 
     + '/q/'
     + cast(id as nvarchar)
     + '|'
     + title as question
     , 'http://' 
     + site 
     + '/users/'
     + cast(owneruserid as nvarchar)
     + '|'
     + displayname as [user]
from #all_posts

drop table #all_posts

drop procedure #recursesiteurl
drop procedure #siteurl
```

Your results look like this:

[image: tweeted posts across the network]

SEDE is only updated once a week, on Sunday at 03:00 UTC. Do give the awesome [SEDE Tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) a try and/or say Hi in [chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede) if you have any further inquiries.

I checked the [Stack API 2.2](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions#pagesize=10&order=desc&sort=activity&filter=default&site=aviation&run=true) but I don't see a flag for tweeted in the [question type](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/question) so a userscript is not going help either to get instant notifications.

Comment: Any particular reason there is (or should be?) none?

Comment: Beyond nobody asked for it I can't imagine a reason.

Comment: Still no notification @BCLC, as of Dec 2018 (but that's OK, I don't care).