# Is there a shortcut for accessing the posts/revisions when an edit hasn't been made?

Tags: feature-request, support, edits, revisions-list

Edit 2: Let me reopen to have the ff as answer:

@BCLC I usually just click the Timeline icon, then manually replace "timeline" with "revisions" in the URL. –
41686d6564
Dec 19 '21 at 23:42
@41686d6564 eh fine i guess that's something. thanks! –
BCLC
Dec 20 '21 at 12:02

---

Edit 1: I'm going to edit this post so I can see the revisions and stuff now that I've successfully flagged my own post.

---

This [sff question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/258387/is-platinum-end-meant-to-refer-to-the-biblical-story-of-elijah-1-kings-194-7) of mine got closed, but I didn't submit any edits (past the 5 minutes or whatever thing) so I had to manually change the URL from

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/258387/is-platinum-end-meant-to-refer-to-the-biblical-story-of-elijah-1-kings-194-7

to

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/258387/revisions

to really see the specific details of

> Post Closed as "Needs more focus" by Valorum, A Rogue Ant., Chenmunka, DavidW, LogicDictates
> occured 9 hours ago

This kind of issue also pops up like if my post gets into the hot network or is [tweeted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/262201/how-do-i-get-notified-if-se-tweets-my-question) but there isn't quite a readily accessible link to see it unless I make an edit.

Comment: @bobble it's the next best thing i guess but i still want to the posts-revisions thing please

Comment: In that case, how about this? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168765/show-link-to-revision-history-when-there-are-revisions-but-no-edits

Comment: @bobble yes definitely. i'll flag this post now. but man/girl 8 years and still not directly? hell.

Answer (score 0):

Yes: the Timeline view, accessible from the clock-like icon to the left of the question:

[image: Screenshot of buttons to the left of the question, with the bottom one circled]

That will show you, among other things, an entry for when the question was closed:

[image: Screenshot of timeline item: "9 hours ago, history, closed, Valorum A Rogue Ant. Chenmunka DavidW LogicDictates, Needs more focus"]

Comment: it's the next best thing i guess but i still want to the posts-revisions thing please

Comment: @BCLC I usually just click the Timeline icon, then manually replace "timeline" with "revisions" in the URL.

Comment: @41686d6564 eh fine i guess that's something. thanks!